# Multidimensional Gaussian Integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, convolution, gaussian-integral, gaussian

I am trying to integrate something of the form
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\ \left(\mathbf{d}-x\mathbf{s}\right)^TC^{-1}\left(\mathbf{d}-x\mathbf{s}\right)\}\exp\{\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\left(x-\mu\right)^2\}
$$
which is of course the same as
$$
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\ \left(\mathbf{d}-x\mathbf{s}\right)^TC^{-1}\left(\mathbf{d}-x\mathbf{s}\right) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(x-\mu\right)^2\}.
$$
(note bolded variable are vectors and $C$ is a symmetric square matrix.) So basically I'm convolving two Gaussians, but the variable being integrated is multiplied by a constant ($\mathbf{S}$) in the first term. I've tried working this out to no avail, any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Simplify the exponent... which corresponds to a shift of the center of the Gaussian.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not sure I see the simplification. Obviously $(x-\mu)^2$ can be expanded but it's not obvious to me how this helps.

Comment: When all else fails, write the matrix multiplication out explicitly.

Comment: @user619894:  Make the substitution $x \to y + \mu$ and see...

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a one-dimensional integral $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{a x^2 + b x + c} dx$ with scalar coefficients $a, b, c$ found from
$$(\boldsymbol d - x \boldsymbol s)^t C (\boldsymbol d - x \boldsymbol s) =
\boldsymbol d^t C \boldsymbol d -
 x (\boldsymbol d^t C \boldsymbol s + \boldsymbol s^t C \boldsymbol d) +
 x^2 \boldsymbol s^t C \boldsymbol s.$$
For symmetric $C$, $\boldsymbol d^t C \boldsymbol s = \boldsymbol s^t C \boldsymbol d$.